# how to extend kohana user auth module

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-auth

So i'm using kohana user module, and i would like to extend my register page, now it adds username, email, and password but i would like to add some extra fields, and i just can't find where can i do it.

I found `function action_register` which leads to `Auth::instance()->register($_POST, true);` so i found this `function register($fields)` which leads to `$user = ORM::factory('user');` and `$user->create_user($fields, array()` so i'm stuck somewhere here, i'm not even sure if i'm going the right path...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just create **user.php** file under *application/classes/model* folder and put this inside:

```
<?php

defined('SYSPATH') or die('No direct access allowed.');

class Model_User extends Model_Auth_User
{
   public function create_user($values, $expected)
   {
      // Your definition of the function
   }
}
```

After checking the register function, here is the place for other fields (line 22-27):

```
$user->create_user($fields, array(
                                'username',
                                'password',
                                'email',
                                'user_type',
                                'other field',
                                'other field2',
                        ));
```

Of course you'll need to have `other_field` and `other_field2` exist in your table.

Comment: This is completely wrong, i already have everything fylly completed i just need to find where the actual query is executed so i could add extra fields

Comment: Exnted the `create_user` function then if you already got everything flying?

Comment: that function looks like this http://pastebin.com/fqk61PH7
and it makes no sense to me..

Comment: It makes perfect sense. It creates a user by calling ORM functions - first values, then create. It also checks if password is not empty. I suggest you go through the ORM tutorial to get the basics.

Comment: okay so how do i send extra values, because i already created new fields in databse i just need to add those values

Comment: You need to show your `Auth::instance()->register` function but basically you should just pass the `$_POST` and expected array

Comment: here it is, http://pastebin.com/eBQb5aJW i added `user_type`, but it doesn't do the trick

Comment: Never mind, i've tried reseting everything and did it again, and it finaly works after 10h of failing it works ;d thanks for your help