# Kohana 3 auth username as number

Tags: authentication, kohana, kohana-3, kohana-orm, kohana-auth

I want to use numbers as username in Kohana Auth. For example, username 100001? 
While adding new user Kohana returns me error: ORM_Validation_Exception [ 0 ]: Failed to validate array
Is is possible to user numbers as username in Kohana?

Comment: Numbers should be no problem. Could you please post the piece of code that creates a User?

Answer (score 0):

***EDIT:** [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8606023/1791115) looks simpler and better than mine, but try to understand it at all.*

---

You need to extend User Model, I'll help you using auth with the ORM driver.

**Steps to extend User Model:**

1. If you didn't yet, configure Auth module to use orm and create a database table with the fields you want. [Here is a good example](http://blog.mixu.net/2010/09/06/step-by-step-guide-to-kohana-3-auth/) of how to doing it (It's an old tutorial using ko3.1 but you can still learn from it). **PS.:** you can have any columns at the 'users' table and you don't need to have the 'username' column if you do not want.
2. Open and read carefully this file: `MODULES/orm/classes/model/auth/user.php` (It's self documented and I hope you understand it. If not, stop reading this answer here and read the kohana docs. Some shortcuts: [Auth - Kohana User Guide](http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/auth/), [Auth (orm) methods](http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/api/Model_Auth_User), [addons:auth](http://docs.kohanaphp.com/addons/auth)
3. Copy the file (don't edit the original) to `APPPATH/classes/model/auth/user.php` and edit it how you want. Some *functions* that you may like to edit are: `rules`, `filters` and `unique_key` (<- useful). Be creative, you also can add custom functions.
4. Test and change whatever else needed.

---

You can change the login method to works as you like. You can set login by e-mail, make a custom validation method or parse values before saving in the database (see `public function filters()`). This is helpful for whatever you try to do with auth module using ORM... But... if you really don't want to use ORM, you can build your own driver, [learn how](http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/auth/driver/develop).

*I made this some time ago in **kohana 3.2** but I think you won't get problems with 3.3. If you still have questions, [this question](http://forum.kohanaframework.org/discussion/8241/custom-schema-with-auth-module/p1) on kohana forum may help.*